# Parsing ImageGetter image as text

Tags: android, android-edittext

Using ImageGetter and HTML, I have some emoticons in an edittext (code below), however I want to be able to recognize these images later in the edittext so it can be stored as a string. Does anyone know how to retrieve this, or should I keep a string updated with string value instead.
Thanks

```
ImageGetter imggtr = new ImageGetter()
        {
            public Drawable getDrawable(String source)
            {
                Drawable d = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(getEmoticonDrawable(position));
                d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
                return d;
            }
        };

Spanned cs = Html.fromHtml("<img src='" + getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(getEmoticonDrawable(position))
                + "'/>", imggtr, null);
mEditor.append(cs);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you should keep a separate string in memory. If you try to parse the html back to a string, it's going to be complicated and not very flexible.

Comment: Dammit, was hoping there would be a way to avoid that! Thanks